# how to use scrapy-rotating-proxies with full settings or rotate ip/per request?

Tags: python-3.x, api, proxy, scrapy, http-proxy

hello folks,
I am scraping a website and using scrapy-rotating-proxies, however i also tried other proxies but they are not suited my requirements or i can't implement them as i want.

There are lots of APIs and I want to fetch APIs like one ip per request. one time when i run the scraper, i have max 100 ips for use but it is not using all and reanimating some of them. you can see some logs below:

```
2020-11-06 09:35:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-06 09:35:56 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 1, unchecked: 87, reanimated: 1, mean backoff time: 122s)
2020-11-06 09:36:26 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 1, unchecked: 87, reanimated: 1, mean backoff time: 122s)
2020-11-06 09:36:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-06 09:36:56 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 1, unchecked: 87, reanimated: 1, mean backoff time: 122s)
2020-11-06 09:37:26 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 1, unchecked: 87, reanimated: 1, mean backoff time: 122s)
2020-11-06 09:37:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 21 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-06 09:37:56 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 1, unchecked: 87, reanimated: 1, mean backoff time: 122s)
2020-11-06 09:37:56 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: 1 proxies moved from 'dead' to 'reanimated'
2020-11-06 09:37:59 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <https://92.60.190.249:50335> is DEAD
2020-11-06 09:37:59 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=243&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2> with another proxy (failed 3 times, max retries: 5)
2020-11-06 09:37:59 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Proxy is detected https://92.60.190.249:50335
2020-11-06 09:37:59 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.146 Safari/537.36
2020-11-06 09:38:10 [rotating_proxies.expire] DEBUG: Proxy <https://162.223.89.220:8080> is GOOD
2020-11-06 09:38:10 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=243&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2> (referer: https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=243&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2)
2020-11-06 09:38:10 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
2020-11-06 09:38:26 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 1, unchecked: 85, reanimated: 2, mean backoff time: 249s)
2020-11-06 09:38:56 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 22 pages (at 1 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-11-06 09:38:56 [rotating_proxies.middlewares] INFO: Proxies(good: 1, dead: 1, unchecked: 85, reanimated: 2, mean backoff time: 249s)
```

INFO: Proxies(good: 0, dead: 1, unchecked: 87, reanimated: 1, mean backoff time: 122s)
see there i don't want to reanimate ips because there are '87' unchecked ip's still remaining. if i send 1 ip per request so the webiste will not catch me and send me a valid response.

My standalone spider which i am using:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import json
from micheal_app import db, server
import ast
from micheal_app import db
import requests as r
from micheal_app.models import Top_sales_data, Categories
from parsel import Selector
import random
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


headers = {
    'authority': 'shopee.com.my',
    'method': 'GET',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
    'if-none-match': '*',
    'x-api-source': 'pc',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'x-shopee-language': 'en'
}
if server.pythonanywhere:
    path = '/home/wholesalechina/mysite/proxies.txt'
else:
    path = 'D:\Freelancer\Orders\micheal git\proxies.txt'


class TopSalesAutoScraper(Spider):
    name = 'top_sales_auto_scraper'
    start_urls = ['https://free-proxy-list.net', 'https://www.sslproxies.org/']
    proxies = []
    li = [1, 2, 3]
    # allowed_domains = ['shopee.com', 'shopee.com.my', 'shopee.com.my/api/']

    custom_settings = {
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED': 'True',
        # The initial download delay
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY': '1',
        # The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY': '60',
        # The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
        # each remote server
        'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': '1.0',

        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': '1',

        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
            'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
            'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 500,
            # ...
            'rotating_proxies.middlewares.RotatingProxyMiddleware': 610,
            'rotating_proxies.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
            # ...
        },
        'ROTATING_PROXY_LIST_PATH': path,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        # Removing that category data from database
        for i in self.li:
            cat_data = Categories.query.filter_by(id=i).first()
            Top_sales_data.query.filter_by(category=cat_data.category).delete()
        db.session.commit()

        f = open('proxies.txt', 'w')
        for url in self.start_urls:
            req = r.get(url)

            response = Selector(text=req.text)
            table = response.css('table')
            rows = table.css('tr')
            cols = [row.css('td::text').getall() for row in rows]

            for col in cols:
                if col and col[4] == 'elite proxy' and col[6] == 'yes':
                    self.proxies.append('https://' + col[0] + ':' + col[1])
            for proxy in self.proxies:
                f.write(proxy+'\n')

            print('proxies found: {0}'.format(len(self.proxies)))
        f.close()

    def start_requests(self):
        # getting all categories
        all_categories = []
        for i in self.li:
            all_categories.append(Categories.query.get(i))
        # Looping through all categories and their subcategories
        for category in all_categories:
            data = ast.literal_eval(category.subcategories)
            for d in data:
                subcat_url = d['subcategory url']
                id = subcat_url.split('.')[-1]
                headers['path'] = '/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={0}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'.format(
                    id)
                headers['referer'] = 'https://shopee.com.my{0}?page=0&sortBy=sales'.format(
                    subcat_url)
                url = 'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={0}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'.format(
                    id)

                yield Request(url=url, headers=headers, callback=self.parse,
                             meta={'proxy': None},
                              cb_kwargs={'subcat': d['subcategory name'], 'category': category.category})

    def parse(self, response, subcat, category):
        try:
            jdata = json.loads(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
        except Exception as e:
            print(
                'This is failed subcat url: {0} and tring again.'.format(subcat))
            print('and the exception is: {0}'.format(e))
            yield Request(response.url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse,
                          cb_kwargs={'subcat': subcat, 'category': category})
        else:
            items = jdata['items']

            for item in items:
                name = item['name']
                image_path = item['image']
                absolute_image = 'https://cf.shopee.com.my/file/{0}_tn'.format(
                    image_path)
                subcategory = subcat
                monthly_sold = item['sold']
                price = float(item['price'])/100000
                price = '{:.2f}'.format(price)
                total_sold = item['historical_sold']
                location = item['shop_location']
                stock = item['stock']
                shop_id = str(item['shopid'])
                item_id = str(item['itemid'])

                # making product url
                if name[0] == '-':
                    name = name[1:]
                p_name = name.replace(
                    ' ', '-').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(
                    '/', '').replace('--', '-').replace('+', '').replace(
                    '%', '').replace('#', '')
                pro_url = 'https://shopee.com.my/' + \
                    p_name + '-i.' + shop_id + '.' + item_id

                top_data = Top_sales_data(photo=absolute_image, product_name=name, category=category,
                                          subcategory=subcategory, monthly_sold=monthly_sold, price=price,
                                          total_sold=total_sold, location=location, stock=stock,
                                          product_url=pro_url)
                db.session.add(top_data)
        db.session.commit()


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(TopSalesAutoScraper)
process.start()
```

I am checking in an try and except block that if response if 200 but an empty json object then i am yielding again so i am expecting that yielding again will be change ip or if not then how to change it.
see the below parse code again:

```
def parse(self, response, subcat, category):
            try:
                jdata = json.loads(response.body.decode('utf-8'))
            except Exception as e:
                print(
                    'This is failed subcat url: {0} and tring again.'.format(subcat))
                print('and the exception is: {0}'.format(e))
                yield Request(response.url, dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse,
                              cb_kwargs={'subcat': subcat, 'category': category})
```